# Point Spectrum, Spectrum for Operator

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

I am having trouble finding the spectrum and point spectrum of the following operator.

$T:C[0,1] \to C[0,1]$

$Tf(x) = \int_0^xf(t)dt  \quad   x\in[0,1]$

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What did you try? Can you find the operator $T-\lambda I$?

Comment: Yes I have attempted that. Unfortunately the integral is confusing me.

Comment: Hint: There is a differential equation hiding in this question, can you find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we had a non-zero $\lambda$ in the point spectrum. What does it mean for something to be in the point spectrum?  It means that $$(T-\lambda)f=0.$$ That is, $$\int\limits_0^x f(s)\, ds=\lambda f(x).$$ Note that, via the FTC, $T$ sends $f$ to a differentiable function. If we differentiate the above, we have the differential equation $f=\lambda f'.$ This has solutions of the form $f(x)=ce^{x/\lambda}$ (which needs that $\lambda\neq 0)$. If we evaluate this at $x=0,$ we get that $f(0)=c.$ However, we can see from our integral equation that at $x=0,$ $\lambda f(0)=0.$ So, if $\lambda\neq 0,$ then $c=0,$ implying $f\equiv 0.$ So, there is no non-zero point spectra. The $\lambda=0$ case is trivial. I'll leave it to you to discuss the general spectrum. (Hint: what properties does this operator have?)

EDIT: Discussed conclusion briefly in comments

Comment: $0$ is also not in the point spectrum. It is in the spectrum though.

Comment: Correct. I was leaving a bit for the OP to conclude.

Comment: Thank you for the help.

Comment: hi @cmk I've read somewhere that K is compact, I don't know how to prove this but what I could think of is to show that closure of $T(K_1(0))$ is compact. And thus the spectrum is at most countable and can only accumulate to $0$. I'm so confused here, could you please explain why $T$ is compact and what does the last statement mean? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: @HồngNgọcTrương Indeed, one can show that $T$ is compact using the Arzela-Ascoli theorem (alternatively, the Hilbert-Schmidt kernel theorem). For a compact, non-self adjoint operator, every non-zero element of the spectrum is an eigenvalue, and the eigenvalues can only accumulate at $0$. This is all fine here, as there are no eigenvalues. In particular (since the spectrum is non-empty), the only element of the spectrum is $0$ (you can also see this via the Fredholm alternative).

Comment: @cmk thank you for the explanation, I'm trying to figure out the approximate spectrum of this operator as well. Could you please give some advice on this?

Comment: @HồngNgọcTrương here's a simple hint: can the approximate point spectrum be empty?

Comment: @cmk If approximate point spectrum is empty, by definition, $T -\lambda I$ is always bounded from below for all $\lambda$. But this is the contradiction because $T -\lambda I$ has to be bounded from below for some $\lambda$ so that the spectrum is not empty?

Comment: @HồngNgọcTrương yup! If $T-\lambda I$ was bounded below for all $\lambda,$ then $T-\lambda I$ would be injective (i.e. would have eigenvalues).  So, you know that it's a non-empty subset of the spectrum, which only contains $0$. Hence, it is exactly the spectrum!

Answer (score 3):

The [point spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_(functional_analysis)#Point_spectrum) $\sigma_p(T)$ of $T$ is precisely the set of eigenvalues of $T$; if

$Tf = \lambda f, \tag 1$

then

$\displaystyle \int_0^x f(s) \; ds = Tf = \lambda f(x); \tag 2$

since

$f(x) \in C[0, 1], \tag 3$

any such $f(x)$ satisfying (1) with $\lambda \ne 0$ is continuously differentiable; thus for such $\lambda$ we may write

$f(x) = \lambda f'(x); \tag 4$

the unique solution to this ordinary differential equation is well-known to be

$f(x) = f(0)e^{x/\lambda}, \; x \in [0, 1]; \tag 5$

however, when (5) is substituted into (2) we obtain

$\lambda f(x) = \displaystyle \int_0^x f(0)e^{s/\lambda} \; ds = f(0) \lambda(e^{x/\lambda} - 1)$
$= f(0)\lambda e^{x/\lambda} - f(0)\lambda = \lambda f(x) - \lambda f(0); \tag 6$

with $\lambda \ne 0$ this yields

$\lambda f(0) = 0 \Longrightarrow f(0) = 0 \Longrightarrow f(x) = 0; \tag 7$

but $f(x) = 0$ is by definition not admissible as an eigenvector/eigenfunction; thus $\sigma_p(T)$ consists of at most $0$, which is certainly not an admissible eigenvalue of $T$ either, for then (2) becomes;

$\displaystyle \int_0^x f(s) \; ds = 0, \tag 8$

which differentiated implies

$f(x) = 0, \; \forall x \in [0, 1], \tag 9$

which is not an admissible eigenvector.  Therefore,

$\sigma_p(T) = \emptyset. \tag{10}$